# jQuery ajax + audio mp3 ogg doesn't play in IE9

Tags: ajax, html, audio

I've got few files I want to play on website, and to change it I used ajax, code below:

```
<div id="play"></div>
<div id="list">
    <span id="1">audio 1</span><br />
    <span id="2">audio 2</span><br />
    <span id="3">audio 3</span><br />
    <span id="4">audio 4</span><br />
    <span id="5">audio 5</span><br />
    <span id="6">audio 6</span><br />
    <span id="7">audio 7</span><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list span').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "play.php",
            data: { file: $(this).attr('id') }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            $('#play').html(msg);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is play.php:

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="auto" autobuffer="autobuffer">
    <source src="get-file.php?v=<?php echo 'ogg#'.intval($_GET['file']).''); ?>" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="get-file.php?v=<?php echo 'mp3#'.intval($_GET['file']).''); ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and in `get-file.php` i check which file i want to play and type of file and using headers I return file. The problem is in ***IE9***, if I use ajax I get `Your browser does not support the audio element.`, if I run audio... straight in browser, it works fine. How to fix this ajax thing in IE?

Comment: can you do  `alert(msg)` and show us what you see?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. The problem was with code which was returned, I forgot to remove `html`, `head`, etc. from play.php file, in result those tags were in `div`.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it yourself.